# google plus one button statistics

Tags: google-plus-one

I would like to know how to get the value for the +1 value((if there are 10 clicks +1 button, store 10 as a variable). This would be helpful for analysis purposes.
I know the count parameter is only Boolean or  plusone.state returns on/off but is there something like plusone.value?  ( i tried it, it's undefined)

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Download the following url: `https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?count=true&url=URLENCODED_URI` via your favorite automatic method (curl, wget, file_get_contents, etc...)

`URLENCODED_URI` is the site you which to know the number of +1's for, e.g. `http://www.google.com`

For example, fetch the URI `https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/%2B1/fastbutton?count=true&url=http://www.google.com/` and locate the first occurance of `window.__SSR = {'c': 32414.0 ,'si'`. Preferably use regexp for this, but I'll leave the implementation to you and your chosen programming language.

The float number following 'c' is the number of +1's the site have. For google.com this is 32.414. Don't worry about it being a float, it is allways an integer in float format, so you can safely convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented API for this described here - http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/

Answer (score 2):

Directions for +1 button tracking can be found at http://yoast.com/plus-one-google-analytics/

On the button creation screen, create a js callback then track the clicks using Google analytics with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function plusone_vote( obj ) {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','plusone',obj.state]);
  }
</script>
```

Alternately, use the javascript callback to track it any way you wish.